# Should if be followed by else

Tags: java

```
public int example1(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int example2(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a preferred standard for these two function? As in, should "if" always be followed by "else" in functions like this?

Edit: For example, I have seen equals defined like the following? Are some of you saying you would remove the "else"?

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    if (otherObject == null)
        return false;
    else if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        return false;
    else
    {
        MyClass otherMyClass = (MyClass) otherObject;
        return (variable.equals(otherMyClass.variable));
    }
}
```

Comment: For readability, yes.

Comment: In such cases, `else` is really not needed, and it's quite clear, although that's really a personal opinion. That wouldn't effect on performance.

Comment: In this case, I never use else and I put a comment "// Default case" to make it clear.

Comment: I've voted to close as "primarily opinion-based". There is not going to be one correct answer for this type of question.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really an accepted standard for this.

For instance, the popular code-improving tool ReSharper will prompt you to "remove the redundant else" block in this case, as you could easily write it without else.

But conversely some people will say that using an else block is more readable.

For the case you provide as an example, I would say the simplest option is

```
return (a > b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return `boolean` value itself

```
return a > b;
```

Comment: This is a very simple example. I am asking for along the lines when checking if exceptions should be thrown, when a large amount if "if,if-else" statements occur, if the actual execution should occur by itself or inside of an "else" block.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "predefined standard" for this.

There are some coding conventions for Java, see for example [Java Code Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), but I never saw one covering this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference and complexity.
This is a simple case, so you don't really need to put it in an else.
For more complex cases, I would recommend using `else (if)`

Of course this example might not be the best, since you can also shorten it to: `return a > b`

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical deferences in this two cases. Normally else is needed if there are more than two possibility. Consider the following case

```
if(a>2){
    return "GOOD";
}else if(a>1){
    return "BAD";     
}else{
    return null;
}
```

You can use following for your case

```
return a>b ;// it self retun true or false

return (a>b) ? true:false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code-wise it doesn't matter. Putting in the else or not is just a question of coding style, and that varies greatly.

To me the code looks as follows:

With else: You have an alternate path for your if that can occur and you know it and handle it gracefully.

Without else: "I don't know how we got here either, so lets return something that doesn't hurt that much..."